# facebook local currency payments error

Tags: facebook, facebook-payments

I have a questions of facebook local currency payments error.

Today I recieved this message:

*"We didn't receive all the information we needed from this app to complete your purchase. You haven't been charged for this purchase, so please try again. If you keep seeing this error, contact the app developer."*

And I don't understand what the reason. Yesterday I think it worked fine.

### JS request

```
var obj = {
action: "purchaseitem"
method: "pay"
product: "https://www.sozzial.com/fb/subscriptions.html"
quantity: "50"
quantity_max: 5000
quantity_min: 1
request_id: "3MJhipp24N0THO+eExGvsdoRZKsF+8vsAD3Po1NRrqCTKSwlDKRO4Wytwh+gP1UrloU37lOJC9cXF7FOLSBAosoXIugOrNtAEMOobnxm6Bzhi7+eWIASl4jA1lNcG3AndHyNfv0OI+IPLXspH76QslI099c="
};  
FB.ui(obj, verifyPayment);
```

Answer (score 2):

We have managed to get rid of this error by submitting the graph object URL (in your case [this link](http://sozzial.com/fb/subscriptions.html)) to the Facebook Object Debugger at: [Facbook Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Answer (score 2):

I had this error because all my payments were done using same request_id.

Comment: It looks like part of your answer is missing?

Comment: I had this error because all my payments were done using same request_id.